# Can I sum summands within square root?

Tags: radicals

For example, here's an expression: $\sqrt{x^2 + x^2}$. Will it be equal to
$\sqrt{2x^2}$?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: When $a=b$ you can replace $a$ by $b$ *everywhere*.

Comment: To emphasize, the summands need to be under *the same* square root.  $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x}$ is not the same as $\sqrt{2x}$.  That said, this should have been covered by the "B" in BEDMAS or whatever [order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) mnemonic you learned.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. $$\sqrt{x^2+x^2}\equiv \sqrt{2x^2}$$

However, be careful that $$\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^2}}\neq\sqrt{2x^2}\neq\sqrt{x^2}+\sqrt{x^2}$$